# Error - Undefined function 'imbinarize' for input arguments of type 'double' in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

when I calculate threshold using entropy and the convert grayscale image to binary image using imbinarize(img,T) it shows the error. How to deal with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imbinarize` uses a 256 bin image histogram to compute Otsu's threshold, so it expects a 'uint' image.

From the error we can deduce that your image is `double`, so just convert it to `uint`:

```
img = im2uint8(img)
```

and then run imbinarize on top of im

```
im_binarized = imbinarize(img,T)
```

**EDIT:**

Also your problem might be that you don't have the image processing toolbox installed.

You can threshold an image without the toolbox, just do:

```
im_binarized = im > T;   % where T is your threshold
```

Comment: Undefined function 'im2unit8' for input arguments of type 'double'. show this error

Comment: Probably you don't have the image processing toolbox installed. See my edit to threshold an image without the toolbox. Otherwise install the toolbox.